# Enqueue JobRunr Background Job with lambda subclass of abstract class

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jobrunr

I want to use JobRunr for scheduling tasks which are defined as follows:

```
@Component
public class TaskExecutionListener implements ApplicationListener<TaskEvent> {
    private final List<Task> tasks;
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(TaskEvent event) {
        BackgroundJob.enqueue(() -> tasks.get(0).process()
    }
}

abstract class Task {
    abstract void process();
}

@Component
class Task1 extends Task{
    void process() {
    }
}

@Component
class Task2 extends Task {
    void process() {
    }
}
```

But I get the exception "org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type 'my.Task' available: expected single matching bean but found 2:
...

Is there a way to use JobRunr this way. It seems to me that the reason for not finding exactly one specific Task class is the serialization process of JobRunr, which serialize my.Task instead of my.Task1.
Can anyone give me some direction?

Comment: Well - I tried reproducing your issue but all works well when I try it with a unit test in JobRunr - the actual class name in the Job Details is `Task1`. Could you setup a repo that reproduces this?

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time look over and trying reproducing it!
I strpiped down my app and pushed it to https://gitlab.com/examples57/jobrunr-test.
Just run with java 17

Comment: See https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/issues/593